# I try to create S3 bucket by python but got invalid syntax

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Here is my code below, could anyone tell me why this happens please? thank you so much!

```
    import boto3

aws_resource = boto3.resource("s3")
bucket = aws_resource.Bucket("andrew_bucket_01")

response = bucket.create(
    ACL='public-read-write',
    CreateBucketConfiguration={
        'LocationConstraint': 'us-east-2'
    },
)
print(response)
```

[image]

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 2):

Bucket name can't contain underscores. Also looks like you're trying to access the bucket before you create it..try the example from the docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/create-bucket-overview.html

Comment: Agreed. The bucket needs to conform to Domain Name rules, since the bucket name forms part of the URL when accessing objects. Underscores are not permitted in Domain Names, so they are also not permitted in names of S3 Buckets.